# Geometric result proof using Vector Algebra

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vectors

I am a second year open university undergraduate math student and I am taking a first course on vector calculus. I am trying to prove the below result in geometry using vector algebra. I would like to have my proof verified/simplified if necessary, any inputs will be extremely valuable.

As an aside, what's a good physics book for a typical undergraduate student, that applies the ideas in Vector calculus, that I can pleasure read and solve along side the mathematics?

> Lines drawn through a point $E$ and the vertices $A,B,C,D$ of a tetrahedron cut the planes of the opposite faces in $A',B',C',D'$. Show that the sum of the ratios in which these points divide $EA,EB,EC,ED$ is $-1$.

**Proof.**

From the theorem on co-planar points, we know that, we can always assign non-zero weights $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ to four co-planar points $A,B,C,D$, such that they form a self-centroidal set.

$\alpha A + \beta B +\gamma C + \delta D = 0\\
\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 0$

Consider the points $A',B',C',D'$ lying in the plane of the four triangular faces - $BCD$, $CDA$, $DAB$, $ABC$.

Since, $B,C,D,A'$ are co-planar, four non-zero weights can be assigned such that $B,C,D,A'$ form a self-centroidal set.

$\beta b + \gamma c + \delta d + \alpha' a' = 0\\
\beta + \gamma + \delta + \alpha' = 0$

$\implies\beta b + \gamma c + \delta d = (\beta + \gamma + \delta)a' $

On similar lines, we can write 4 equations for position vectors $a',b',c',d'$:

$\beta b + \gamma c + \delta d = (\beta + \gamma + \delta) a'$

$\alpha a + \gamma c + \delta d = (\alpha + \gamma + \delta) b'$

$\alpha a + \beta b + \delta d = (\alpha + \beta + \delta) c'$

$\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma) d'$

Subtracting expression (1) - (2),

$\beta b - \alpha a = (\beta + \gamma + \delta) a' - (\alpha + \gamma + \delta) b'\\
\beta b + (\alpha + \gamma + \delta) b' = \alpha a + (\beta + \gamma + \delta) a'\\
\frac{\beta b + (\alpha + \gamma + \delta) b'}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta} = \frac{\alpha a + (\beta + \gamma + \delta) a'}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta} = e$

$E$ is the point of intersection of $AA,BB'$. Moreover,

$\alpha a + (\beta + \gamma + \delta) a' = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)e\\
a'=\frac{(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)e - \alpha a}{\beta + \gamma + \delta}$

Thus, $A'$ divides $EA$ externally in the ratio $-\alpha/(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)$. Likewise, $B',C',D'$ divide $EB,EC,ED$ externally in the ratios $-\beta/(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta), -\gamma/(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta), -\delta/(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)$ respectively. The sum of these ratios is :

$$\begin{aligned}&\frac{-\alpha}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta}+\frac{-\beta}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta}+\frac{-\gamma}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta}+\frac{-\delta}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta}\\&=-\frac{(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta} \\&= -1 \end{aligned}$$

Comment: for the physics question, i thought about that today too, and i found Richard Feynman's Lectures on Physics.  I started reading them today, and they are really good to read, and a lot of fun.  I think there are exercises too, but you would have to look for them, i guess. I found this link http://b-ok.xyz/book/2139627/eed0be/?_ir=1

Comment: I agree, they build a gut, intuitive feel for physics and are absolute fun! Let me take a look at the exercises.

Comment: Spivak physics for mathematicians?